# System hang when using SSHFS

Tags: nautilus, ssh, sshfs, nemo, caja

This is just a quick note that I want to share with others. It is about the problem that I encountered with my office machine. It was hanging continuously when ssh mount was used.
The main problem is, as I assumed, the termination of ssh session, which caused the sshfs not to respond.

The solution for this issue is the 
ServerAliveInterval 60 directive in /etc/ssh/ssh_config file.

Hope this someone help!

Comment: Please split your solution into an answer by clicking the ~"Answer your own question" below.

Comment: I don't understand why is the negative thumb. This is the problem which may occur on any default setup of e.g. Linux Mint or any *buntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution for the above problem is to fire the terminal and enter

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

Add at the end of the file:

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

Save and exit.
Restart ssh with

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Comment: shoud I write this on client or on server?

Comment: on a client machine