nautilus frozen, is there a proper solution?
nautilus is frozen, because of sshfs, a very common issue. Now I cannot kill/restart nautilus. I know there are issues with sshfs but at any moment am I not allowed to hard restart my own software which is nautilus in this case? I tried every pseudo solution available on the web:

killall nautilus or nautilus -q or killall -9 nautilus, with sudo
ps -aux | grep nautilus and then sudo kill <process_id>

I am using ubuntu 22.04.
This is age old question and I am struggling with this for more than a decade. The funny thing is that after sometime (a few hours) things get automatically solved. Or, I must reboot the whole system?
Can anyone please explain why can't I force restart anything I wish?
Please answer only when you know your solution works.
P.S. Sometimes killing sshfs helps, sometimes doesn't. It feels like not everything is in my hands, and luck plays most important role, even in 2024.

Have you seen/tried this https://askubuntu.com/questions/365535/system-hang-when-using-sshfs?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C34.9378

I will try. But my main question remains. Can't I force restart nautilus whenever I want?

Will this do? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080205/nautilus-not-starting-promptly

Or do yu have pkill? it is in mine Ubuntu 22.04, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78762/closing-all-nautilus-windows-from-terminal and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/when-should-i-not-kill-9-a-process

both did not work. Now I am again waiting for nautilus to freeze again so that I can test new solutions.

this might be interesting https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344444/pkill-doesnt-kill

To me, your problem is not Nautilus, it  is tcp/ip it doesn't tell if a connection stopped working. There are 3 ways of working with it, setting serveraliveinterval and serveralivecountmax or install autossh or autofs https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14143/what-is-a-better-way-to-deal-with-server-disconnects-of-sshfs-mounts
